# bfgminer on bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, bfgminer

I am getting this error and looking for guidance.

Error : `Most likely you have input the wrong URL, forgotten to add a port, or have not set up workers`

**config**

```
 server=1
 rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24
 rpcallowip=192.168.2.0/24
 rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
 rpcport=9050
 rpcuser=someuser 
 rpcpassword=somepass
```

**command**

```
bfgminer.exe -o 192.168.2.242:9050 -u someuser -p somepass
bfgminer.exe -o 127.0.0.1:9050 -u someuser -p somepass
```

Comment: In this example, the username in `bitcoin.conf` is `somepass` but on the `bfgminer` command line it is `someuser`.  Perhaps you should double check whether they match in your actual setup.

Comment: don't mind it I misedit them while posting here.

Comment: I have a stupid question. Is bitcoind actually running?

Comment: I am not sure what is bitcoind but bitcoin-qt running and synced. (like 25 GB)